# quicksort recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation, quicksort

In Concrete Mathematics
Textbook by Donald Knuth and Oren Patashnik ,
ch.2 Sum ,sec2.2
He wrote:

> The average number of  comparison steps made  by quicksort when it's applied to $n$ items in random order satisfies the recurrence :
>   $$C_0=0;$$
>   $$C_n = n + 1 + \frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}C_k$$

The question is how he get the relation :

$$C_n = n + 1 + \frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}C_k$$?

Comment: Well, what does the book say? What do you end up with when _you_ [take a close look](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) at the algorithm?

Comment: I think $n+1$ should be $n-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that textbook says nothing about how to deduce that particular recurrence relation, although it has plenty of examples on how to obtain a recurrence relation. In fact, I cannot understand $C_1=1+1+C_0 =2$, which says that we need two comparisons to sort 1 item using quicksort.

If OP's intention is emphasizing how **he** (meaning them, Donald Knuth and Oren Patashnik) get the recurrence relation, then I can only honestly say I have no credible idea beyond a few educated guesses.

If OP's intention is just to know how to deduce the recurrence relation, then [the wikipedia item on quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Using_recurrences) is a nice answer, which I have copied below with minor modification to fit current question.

> Assume that there are no duplicates. When the input is a random permutation, the rank of the pivot is uniform random from 0 to $n − 1$. Then the resulting parts of the partition have sizes i and $n − i − 1$, and $i$ is uniform random from 0 to $n − 1$. So, averaging over all possible splits and noting that the number of comparisons for the partition is $n − 1$, the average number of comparisons over all permutations of the input sequence can be estimated accurately by solving the following recurrence relation.

$$
C(n)=n-1+{\frac 1n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(C(i)+C(n-i-1))=n-1+{\frac 2n}\sum _{i=0}^{n-1}C(i) $$

Please note that in the wikipedia item, $C(1)=1-1+0=0$, which say that we need no comparison to sort 1 item, which looks much more reasonable to me